# Cassandra writing timeout writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, timeout, datastax

I'm trying to insert data into Cassandra. I have a list of 1M4 integer that I want to insert in a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
     node_id bigint,
     screen_name text,
     centrality float,
     friend_follower_id bigint,
     is_friend boolean,
     is_follower boolean,
     PRIMARY KEY ((node_id), friend_follower_id));
```

to insert data I did the following:

```
prepared_statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO {0} (node_id, screen_name, friend_follower_id, centrality, is_follower) VALUES ({1}, {2}, ?, {3}, true)".format("met_table", author_id, author_username, 0.0)
execute_concurrent_with_args(session, prepared_statement, zip(followers))
```

The error  like:

```
cassandra.WriteTimeout: Error from server: code1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed -out received only 0 responses." info={'consistency': LOCAL_ONE, 'received_response':0, 'required_response':1}
```

How can I avoid time out when writing big amount of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error indicates a server-side coordinator timeout. This is governed by the `cassandra.yaml` setting `write_request_timeout_in_ms`. You can try raising that.

This is sometimes observed when a cluster is overwhelmed and server GC pauses hang replicas. However, it's more common at higher consistency levels. You haven't said anything about your cluster size or replication factor. Are you running with RF=3?

Finally, if your cluster allocation can't handle this write workload, it's possible to lighten the load by reducing the `concurrency` parameter to `execute_concurrent_with_args`.

Comment: I'm working on localhost. My replication factor is set to 2.

Comment: I increase (x10) the write_request_timeout but the problem I meet is that make my computer very slow and I think that stuck my code. Half the data have been inserted but the others  hasn't been inserted. I compute the size of the list I want to insert and the size is about 10MB, is that a normal Usecase? Should I divide it in smaller chunk?